# MySQL default empty value

Tags: mysql

I want to apply default empty values to the following table, so that on my website I can display "Not Assigned" for the users that uses the DEFAULT value:

```
    gender ENUM("male", "female"),
    age INT NOT NULL,
```

How would one do this? I've tried assigning `DEFAULT 'N/A'` but of course this won't work for any of the columns since their datatypes are ENUM and INT respectively.
Hope it's not a stupid question.

Comment: When you query test and present n/a if appropriate. NB you cannot store null if column is not null. AND storing age is problematic.

Comment: Is `NULL` not appropriate?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I've done some reading, and I got the impression that in my PHP code I can't check for a variable being 'NULL'. I want to be able to check with a conditional statement if the HTML form haven't been declared, just like an ordinary website "Relationship not specified".

Comment: `if (is_null($row['gender'])) {}` or `if ($row['gender'] === null) {}` works fine in all database libraries I've used.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this. Not sure why I have such a hard time finding easy solutions like yours.